Why didn't the villagers kill the werewolf?
The werewolf doesn't seem that hard to kill.  When David and Jack leave The Slaughtered Lamb, the villagers fret about sending them out to die, have a change of heart and arrive just in time to kill the beast, without much trouble.  Later on, Jack laughs at the idea of needing a silver bullet.
Last, the police weapons team dispatches werewolf #2 easily enough at the end.
The villagers have apparently put up with the curse for hundreds of years ("That star has been there for 200 years" says the innkeeper to the doctor).
Why didn't they just kill it before?
p.s. Alex does say "a werewolf needs to be killed by one who loves them", but that also seems like a red herring in the end.

Should I have used some form of spoiler/reveal mechanism/notice?  It's an old movie, but that might be more problematic with newer material.

I wouldn't worry about it. The ending is fairly predictable

Probably for the same reason I don't kill my neighbour for using his lawnmower at 6am on a Sunday. Because there are consequences and you might go to jail.

Well, you could always blame the event on "a deranged madman".  Especially with the whole village testifying.

@Valorum No jury in the world would vote to convict you.

Maybe they didn't want to find out which of their friends/neighbors was the werewolf.

If the villagers killed the werewolf a long time ago, then what would the movie be about? "An American tourist in London"? /s

@PeterM - Now I'm wondering if Emily in Paris is actually the aftermath of a horror film...

@PeterM If the Colonial Marines had left a pilot in the USS Sulaco (Aliens) that would also have made for a different movie...  great movies, both, but, seems like plot devices you need to swallow first.  Just wondering if I missed anything obvious.

@ItalianPhilosopher I understand what you were asking, and I was just making a flippant remark.  But fundamentally all works of fiction rely on a contrived set of circumstances that don't hold up to logic, and we even have a term of that - "suspension of disbelief"

The townsfolk were covering the werewolf curse up. We're never told why, exactly, but there's ample evidence in the script (all emphasis mine)

WOMAN: You can’t let them go.
DART PLAYER: (angry) Should the world know our
business?!
CHESS PLAYER: It’s murder then.
DART PLAYER: Then murder it is! It’s in God’s
hands now.

From all the world building in the tavern, we have these things:

Everyone in town knew about the werewolf
They probably knew who the werewolf was
They all knew how to avoid the werewolf and just lived with the problem
They wanted to keep it a secret

The only other thing we know is that Werewolf #1 was an old man. As to the coverup, the doctor who treats David (the titular American Werewolf) notes this later

DR. HIRSCH: I tried to investigate the attack. There are no records. The case was closed and now they’ve ‘misplaced’ the file. David’s lacerations were
cleaned and dressed when he arrived here and yet supposedly no doctor
examined him before I did. The Goodman boy is already in the ground so he’s no good to us. So I went to the pub in East Proctor where I was convinced of two
things.
ALEX: Yes.
DR. HIRSCH: They were lying. There were no witnesses, no escaped lunatic. The whole community is hiding the truth of what actually happened up there.
ALEX: And what else?
DR. HIRSCH: I think the village of East Proctor is hiding some dark and terrible secret. I’m convinced that, like David, they believe in this werewolf.

Let's say that a character named Fred, who happens to be the mayor, is the werewolf. You wouldn't necessarily want people running around knowing the truth. Fred runs around on full moons, hunting animals. The locals know to stay indoors, and Fred can't get far enough out of town to hurt anyone else. Fear keeps the locals from talking about it outside the town.
Along comes two ignorant American college kids and they decide to go back out into the night, where Fred is running around. Nobody wants to tell them this or try to stop them. I'm guessing they were hoping Fred wouldn't find them.
It's not clear if it was conscience or the realization that they might not be able to cover up the deaths two foreigners that provoked Mr. Chess and Mr. Dart to go and off the werewolf. Regardless, they go to great lengths to ensure the coverup continues. The old man just died. Without an autopsy, few would question it. And someone in the medical field clearly helped treat David. The dead American... well, it was a lunatic. Targets of convenience. Werewolf? That's crazy talk...

Yeah, I guess that if the werewolf is a sympathetic person most of the time, like David himself and if they know how not to get eaten, they may not want to kill it.  Oh, I definitely caught that they were covering it up, that's only repeated like 20 times ;-)

"Wow killing Fred was way easier than we thought it would be."

I imagine at least part of the reason the townsfolk didn't try to kill the werewolf before is because such an endeavour was likely not without risk.
Sure, you can apparently kill these werewolves with regular bullets. And no, they apparently don't need to be killed by someone they love. But the townsfolk didn't have sniper rifles like the Metropolitan Police, so they had to get pretty close to the werewolf to get a good shot at it, and in doing so, they themselves could've gotten killed, or injured in such a way as to be afflicted with the werewolf's curse.
When the townsfolk actually shot the werewolf, it was busy attacking David (and Jack before that), so its attention was diverted. But if they'd attempted to approach and shoot it without a pair of tourists there to serve as a distraction, then its attention would've been on them, and maybe they could've shot and killed it before it killed or bit any of them, but maybe not.
Why take the risk when you could safely hang out in the pub each full moon? They were probably in there most evenings anyway, so it's not as if they had to go far out of their way to avoid the werewolf.
